# Toggle CodeMirror Theme on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

http://jsbin.com/EzaKuXE/1/edit

I've been trying to change the theme from default to cobalt and so on having it toggle each time you click the button but it switches to the theme once, and doesn't switch back. Hence why I'm here. Can anyone help guide the right direction? This simple task is getting annoying.

I have replaced irrelevant parts of the code with .(dot)

**HTML**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href=http://codemirror.net/doc/docs.css>
.
. 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://codemirror.net/theme/3024-night.css">
.
.
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://codemirror.net/theme/neat.css">
</head>
<body>
  <textarea id=code name=code>
    .
    .
    <iframe id=preview></iframe>

    <p>Select a theme: <select onchange="selectTheme()" id=select>
        <option value="0" selected>default</option>
        .
            .
        <option>night</option>
    </select></p>

  <button id="changetheme" style="margin-top: -35px; float: right;">Cobalt</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
// Initialize CodeMirror editor with a nice html5 canvas demo.
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    styleActiveLine: true,
    matchBrackets: true
});

// Sets the theme
var input = document.getElementById("select");

function selectTheme() {
    var theme = input.options[input.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
    editor.setOption("theme", theme);
}

$(function() {
    $('#changetheme').click(themechange);

    function themechange() {
        if (
            $("#select").val(0)) {
            $("#select").val(7).trigger('change');
        }
        else if (
            $("#select").val(7)) {
            $("#select").val(0).trigger('change');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For toggling content using jQuery, use the toggleClass() function.

http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

```
$(element).toggleClass("className");
```

Comment: I already tried this, and it doesn't work with that I'm trying to do in CodeMirror. Here's the fiddle - http://jsbin.com/EzaKuXE/6/edit

Comment: From your fiddle, I see that you have .toggleClass(".className") with the dot in there. The dot is only used in selectors and not with the toggleClass("className") syntax. See the updated fiddle below which now works: http://jsbin.com/EzaKuXE/11/edit